# Meaning of "un jugo de latita o de latota"?

Tags: definiciones, significado

I recently heard a bartender ask a female customer:

> ¿Usted quiere un jugo de latita o de latota?

The customer got very upset and threw a glass of water at the bartender and then she left.

Why did she get upset?

Comment: Note the way he was playing with the sounds: _latita_ means "little can" (_do you want a juice in a little can?_), while _latota_ does not mean anything but _la tota_ does, as Gorpik nicely exposed. When pronounced, the intentious misunderstanding arises.

Answer (score 12):

You do not mention where this happened, but in some places (Puerto Rico comes to mind) *la tota* is slang for a woman external sexual organs. So the bartender was indeed very rude.

Comment: It happened in Orlando Florida. Which sexual organ is it?

Comment: Sure the bartender was rude. @FrankR check this out http://www.asihablamos.com/www/significado/palabra/tota

Answer (score 5):

According to the *Diccionario de americanismos*, "[tota](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tota)" (also "toto") is a taboo word used in Cuba, Puerto Rico and the Dominican Republic meaning "pussy". So yes, the bartender was asking her if she wanted juice from her pussy.

Answer (score 0):

Latota is a word play. Latota could mean big can, as opposed to latita, which means little can. Latita, latota, same as in mamacita, mamasota.
Or it could mean pussy juice, as in “de la tota”. Toto or tota is a vulgar name for vagina, in Caribbean spanish or argentine spanish slang